# Project Summary Web part Provisioning in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am working on "Project Summary web part" Provisioning in wiki page as well as publishing page too.

Below is my code :

```
  ProjectSummaryWebPart newprojectSummaryWebPart = (ProjectSummaryWebPart)newWebPart;
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProjectSummaryWebPart projectSummaryWebPart = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProjectSummaryWebPart();

                        projectSummaryWebPart.ID = webpartId;
                        projectSummaryWebPart.Title = newprojectSummaryWebPart.Title;
                        projectSummaryWebPart.AllowMinimize = newprojectSummaryWebPart.AllowMinimize;
                        projectSummaryWebPart.AllowZoneChange = newprojectSummaryWebPart.AllowZoneChange;
                        projectSummaryWebPart.AllowHide = newprojectSummaryWebPart.AllowHide;
                        projectSummaryWebPart.AllowClose = newprojectSummaryWebPart.AllowClose;
                        projectSummaryWebPart.ListId = newprojectSummaryWebPart.listID;



                        #region Set Panels In Project Summary Webpart
                        ProjectSummaryPanelConfig panelConfig = new ProjectSummaryPanelConfig();
                        panelConfig.IsLatePanel = newprojectSummaryWebPart.IsLatePanel;
                        if (newprojectSummaryWebPart.DaysToSearch > 0)
                        {
                            //Set DaystoSearch value to display tasks as per the latest due date.
                            //If due date is after 3 days and set value is 3 than only those task displayed in web part which has a due date after 3 days.
                            panelConfig.Enabled = true;
                            panelConfig.DaysToSearch = newprojectSummaryWebPart.DaysToSearch;


                        }
                        projectSummaryWebPart.Panels.Add(panelConfig);
```

I Want to set Panels value in web part. If i am provisioning web part without panel Values than it is working superb. But when i am set panels Value using "ProjectSummaryPanelConfig object" code gives me below error:

> Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Can u help me out as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you initialized the `projectSummaryWebPart.Panels` collection?

Comment: Ya i have initialized